# Infinite product not free

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, direct-product, free-abelian-group

I read that the group $\prod_{n\in{\mathbb N}}\mathbb Z$ is not a free abelian group. Can someone point me to a proof of this fact?

Comment: Can you update your question with the definition of a free Abelian group and try if the axioms fit?

Comment: Do you know the difference between $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ and $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Mathmo123: Could you try to answer the question?

Comment: I don't think there is a trivial proof. Here is one answer: (free $\mathbb{Z}$-module is the same thing as free abelian group) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't an infinite direct product of copies of $\Bbb Z$ a free module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320444/why-isnt-an-infinite-direct-product-of-copies-of-bbb-z-a-free-module)

Comment: Yes it does, thanks!

Comment: The question could have been closed as a duplicate. But, as often happens, I do not understand why it was closed for "lack of context". Did all of the people who voted to close know the answer? If not, why are they voting to close - other people might be interested in the answer.

Comment: incidentally, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936654/help-to-show-that-bigoplus-i-in-mathbbn-mathbbz-cong-operatornamehom/3936670) is the "theorem of Specker" referred to in the answer linked above. as a corollary, Specker's result shows that, rather remarkably, there are only $\aleph_0$ many group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$!