# Hom and direct product on the first factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

It is elementary that for modules over a ring $R$, $\text{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_i A_i,B)=\prod_i \text{Hom}_R (A_i,B)$, and $\text{Hom}_R(A,\prod_i B_i)=\prod_i \text{Hom}_R(A,B_i)$. I am curious that what can we say about $ \text{Hom}_R (\prod_i A_i, B)$? Is there a result concerning this situation? Actually I want to check that $\text{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\prod_{n\in \Bbb N} \Bbb Z,\Bbb Z)$ is whether countable or not.

Comment: The hom functor is left exact on the second entry. On the first entry, the map $\mathrm{Hom}_R(\prod A_i, B)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(\oplus A_i,B)$ is by restriction, and you can have two different maps with the same restriction; just take $B=(\prod A_i)/(\oplus A_i)$ and consider the canonical projection and the zero map.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh I see. I have deleted that part. Thanks

Comment: I think you just misinterpreted what the left exactness means in that case: if you have an exact sequence, the *image* is left exact. So if you have a *surjection* $f\colon X\to Y$, then the induced map $\mathrm{Hom}(Y,B)\to\mathrm{Hom}(X,B)$ is injective, since the map is given by sending $h\colon Y\to B$ to $h\circ f$, and $h\circ f= g\circ f$ implies $h=g$ when $f$ is surjective.

Comment: it is the case that $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z})$ is countable, and it is in fact isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$, but this is quite a non-trivial result. see eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936654/help-to-show-that-bigoplus-i-in-mathbbn-mathbbz-cong-operatornamehom/3936670)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks!